# Why is Connection.PrepareCall() converted to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement

Tags: sql, jdbc, jboss

We are migrating a 10 years old JRun app to JBoss and are struggling with strange JDBC errors
for all of our stored procedure calls that are using SQL local temp table.
All stored procedures are working correctly in the JRun Server with micromedia jdbc driver.

Here is the one of our stack traces:

> Invalid object name '#msgs'. -- a temp table inside the called stored procedure
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(): Line 216
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(): Line 1515
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(): Line 404
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(): Line 350
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(): Line 5696
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(): Line 1715
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(): Line 180
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(): Line 155
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(): Line 285
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(): Line 462
>   gov.ocda.cms2.control.violation.FormServlet.violationApproval(): Line 839
>   gov.ocda.cms2.control.violation.FormServlet.doPost(): Line 72
>   gov.ocda.cms2.core.CMSServlet.service(): Line 46
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(): Line 847

My question is why does `Connection.prepareCall()` return a `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement`?

Is it related to the SQL exception being thrown from JDBC?

Comment: Which database? Show the code which calls the stored procedure, and the stored procedure. AFAIK one of the reasons for the wrapped statement is that JBoss keeps track of these (and it will print warnings, if you do not close them properly). Using temporary tables together with a connection pool conflicts somehow (possibly [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18121386/2390083)).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the connection pooling / JCA resource adapter from JBoss. Connection pools and resource adapters wrap the `Connection` and other derived JDBC objects (like `Statement`) so it can control, restrict and monitor some of the normal JDBC behavior to ensure integrity of the connection pool, distributed transactions etc

This has nothing to do with the error you see.